# Moschi exampe from git gives error Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $.hidden_card

Tags: java, json

I was trying to use moschi from their git tutorial but I keep getting the same error. Link to moschi git https://github.com/square/moshi

Exception in thread "main" com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $.hidden_card

```
public class CardAdapter {

    @ToJson
    String toJson(Card card) {
        return card.rank + card.suit.name().substring(0, 1);
    }

    @FromJson
    Card fromJson(String card) {
        if (card.length() != 2) throw new JsonDataException("Unknown card: " + card);

        char rank = card.charAt(0);
        switch (card.charAt(1)) {
            case 'C': return new Card(rank, Suit.CLUBS);
            case 'D': return new Card(rank, Suit.DIAMONDS);
            case 'H': return new Card(rank, Suit.HEARTS);
            case 'S': return new Card(rank, Suit.SPADES);
            default: throw new JsonDataException("unknown suit: " + card);
        }
    }
}

public class Card {
    char rank;
    Suit suit;

    public Card(char rank, Suit clubs) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = clubs;
    }
}

public class BlackjackHand {
    Card hidden_card;
    List<Card> visible_cards;
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // write your code here
        String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("cards.json")));
        System.out.println(json);
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(new CardAdapter()).build();
        JsonAdapter<BlackjackHand> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(BlackjackHand.class);
        BlackjackHand blackjackHand = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json);

    }
{
  "hidden_card": {
    "rank": "6",
    "suit": "SPADES"
  },
  "visible_cards": [
    {
      "rank": "4",
      "suit": "CLUBS"
    },
    {
      "rank": "A",
      "suit": "HEARTS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You followed the README until the [https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-type-adapters](*Custom Type Adapters*) part, but visibly used the JSON fragment from [https://github.com/square/moshi#built-in-type-adapters](the previous part).

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON serializer does not comply with your data:

- it expects *Card*s instances to be serialized as strings (*"6S", "AH"*),
- when your data contains *Card*s instances serialized as JSON objects (*{"rank": "6","suit": "SPADES"}*)